# How can I add custom text into taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have number of similar computers, which requires some visual identification for the user. Identification is couple letters and number(e.g. XUH1). I've tried to use BgInfo in order to show this information but it's in the background and one should minimize apps in order to see this.

I'm looking for some way to add text on the taskbar, which is always visible, to show identification name. It's Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried creating a "New toolbar..." called `XUH1`?  Once created, it should appear on the right, next to the system tray.  You could save company- or system-related shortcuts in the corresponding folder; and minimize it enough on your taskbar to require users to click a chevron to pop-open the app/doc shortcut list.  Worth a mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create an empty folder in a somewhat hidden location so that no one deletes it (e.g. inside the Windows folder). Name it how you want the computer to be named
- Rightclick the taskbar -> Toolbars, New Toolbar, select the folder you just created

It shows up to the left of tray icons.

[image]